# change color when hovering over option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a select with javascript and filled its options with an array. Afterwards I wrote some jquery to try and change the backgroundColor of the option when I hover over it, but nothing seems to work. everytime I hover over the options they are still highlighted blue.

I'm new to javascript and jquery and this is an idea that I had of why this happens: could this be because there is a standard hover function in a select that will always override mine or am I really overlooking a mistake? Because I tested my code before on divs and the code worked like a charm here

My code:

```
//arraycommObjName is an array with 4 elements to fill my selection
//$('#commObjs') is my select
for (i=0; i < arraycommObjName.length; i++) {
    $('#commObjs').append($('<option class="testoptions"></option>').attr("value", arrayCommObjID[i]).text(arraycommObjName[i]));
}


$(".testoptions").hover(function(e) { 
    $(this).css("background-color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"green":"red") 
})
```

take note yes I know it's better to do this with css but it is asked to me to do it with only javascript and jquery.

Comment: Please also provide your HTML

Comment: You cannot easily change the styling of `select` or `option` elements. If you require this I'd suggest using a library which converts the `select` to other HTML elements which you do have full CSS control over.

Comment: try something like choosen or  select2 plugin these converts the select into ul li then only you may be able to apply css over the element

Comment: Ok thanks alot I will try my luck with a plugin

Comment: As @Rory McCrossan has mentioned it's probably not possible to play with the CSS of the `<option>` elements. I would suggest you to go for a simple "CSS only" drop down menu type solution. You can find many examples over the net.

Comment: @Redu Ye I know a CSS solution would be much better but as I said in my question I have to use javascript, JQuery only so I'm gonna go with a plugin thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) and add some CSS to override the default styles.

Below is an example with some horrific colors to prove you can override the default select2 white and blue colors.

```js
$("#states").select2();
```

```css
#states {
  width: 300px;
}

.select2-results__option {
  color: orange;
  background-color: seashell;
}

.select2-results__option--highlighted {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: darkgreen !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="states">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes I'm currently trying to do this but in my case it's not that easy. You see I'm making a custom component for design studio in eclipse and this does not have html only a component.js to write away javascript and jquery, do you know a way to include a script in a js file? cause at the moment I always get a 'Error: Script error for:' message